# Insert just in many to many Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, orm

I have 2 tables (User and Announcement), now more users can be assigned to one announcement(relation is many to many),
In my controller I have:

```
@Autowired
private AnnouncementService announcementService;

    User user = (User) httpSession.getAttribute("userAccount");
    Announcement announcement = announcementService.getAnnouncement(announcementId);
    user.getAssignedUsersToAnnouncement().add(announcement);
    announcement.getAnnouncementsAssignedToUsers().add(user);
```

I don't want to save these objects again in my DB, I just want to save relations in my third object("Assigned_Users").
       To persist now I should do something like this:

```
announcementService.save(announcement); //due to this will be dublicates in my table
```

---

```
Announcement class{
   @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinTable(name = "Assigned_Users",
           joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "anunt_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")} )
   private Set<User> announcementsAssignedToUsers = new HashSet<User>();
}
```

---

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "Assigned_Users",
        joinColumns =  {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "anunt_id")})
private Set<Announcement> assignedUsersToAnnouncement = new HashSet<Announcement>();
```

The user and announcement which I got there are already in DB,I don't want to save them again. How can I solve this problem, and insert just in many to many table

Answer (score 0):

First, you only need to map ope side of the relation with `@JoinTable`. On the other side you just need to set `mappedBy` attribute. So your relation will look like this

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "Assigned_Users",
       joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "anunt_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")} )
private Set<User> announcementsAssignedToUsers = new HashSet<User>();


@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "announcementsAssignedToUsers")
private Set<Announcement> assignedUsersToAnnouncement = new HashSet<Announcement>();
```

Second, this type of logic should be in the service class, not in the controller. From controller you should just pass the ids to the service method, and then get the needed entities by their id in the service class. Something like this

```
// controller
@Autowired
private AnnouncementService announcementService;

    announcementService.assignUserToAnnouncement(user.getId(), annoucmentId);

// service

@Transactional
public void assignUserToAnnouncement(Long userId, Long announcementId) {
    User user = userRepository.getById(userId);
    Announcement announcement = annRepository.getById();
    user.getAssignedUsersToAnnouncement().add(announcement);
    announcement.getAnnouncementsAssignedToUsers().add(user);
    annRepository.save(announcement);
    userRepository.save(user);
}
```

Comment: this function from service will save again announcement and user? or just update the data from many to many?